# Callback on animation start for transitionFromView:toView:duration

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I am flipping between one view and another using transitionFromView:toView:duration.

My source view is centered in it's parent view. I would also like to center the destination view (as is done in the completion block below).

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:sourceView toView:destView duration:.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        destView.center = destView.superview.center;
    }];
```

Since transitionFromView:toView:duration removes sourceView from it's superview and replaces it with destView, you can't simply run destView.center = destView.superview.center before the call.

Is there a way to run the centering code before the animation starts?

Comment: I'm confused ... running the center code before the animation, like thisdestView.center = destView.superview.center; [UIView transitionFromView:sourceView toView:destView duration:.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        destView.center = destView.superview.center;
    }];

Comment: The destination view's superview isn't set before the call to transitionFromView:toView:duration. transitionFromView removes sourceView from it's superview and replaces it with destView.

Comment: what cycle method are you performing this in? viewDidLoad? viewWillAppear?

Comment: It's in a button-tap event handler.

Comment: That is strange, but here is what you could do, make an object to represent the center like CGPoint center = destView.superview.center; then make the transition call destView.center = center; idk what the "center" object is but that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using transitionWithView:duration:options:animations: for the same effect:

```
self.destView.hidden = YES;
[self addSubview:self.destView];
destView.center = destView.superview.center;
// [self setNeedsLayout]; // I can't remember if this is necessary???

[UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.3 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{

     self.destView.hidden = NO;
     self.sourceView.hidden = YES;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     [self.sourceView removeFromSuperview]; 
     self.sourceView.hidden = NO;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, @bilobatum. This was the right idea and just what I needed. It didn't work out of the box and half wasn't necessary. I replaced it with a variation that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try storing a reference to the point before it is deallocated due to being removed from view by the transition class method call.

```
CGPoint* center = destView.superview.center;
[UIView transitionFromView:sourceView toView:destView duration:.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        destView.center = center;
}];
```